# For which real, symmetric matrices $A$ is $A-A^3$ invertible?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, symmetric-matrices

Question is from a past QR Exam and is exactly as the title:

> For which real, $n \times n$ symmetric matrices $A$ is $A-A^3$ invertible?

$A$ of course commutes with itself and the identity $I_n$, so we can write $A - A^3 = A(I_n + A)(I_n - A)$. So then for $A - A^3$ to be invertible, the matrix $A$ *cannot* have eigenvalues $\lambda = 0,\pm 1$. However, that seems to be independent of whether or not $A$ is symmetric. I must be missing something, because I don't see the connection with $A$ being symmetric.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since $A$ is symmetric, it is diagonalizable and its eigenvalues are real. So, for some invertible matrix $P$, $PAP^{-1}=D$, for some diagonal matrix $D$, and $PA^3P^{-1}=D^3$. Therefore, $P(A-A^3)P^{-1}=D-D^3$ and, since $D$ is diagonal, $D-D^3$ is invertible if and only if none of the eigenvalues of $D$ is $0$, $1$, or $-1$.

Comment: Since they are asking for a characterization of these matrices, I think it is important to emphasize that symmetric matrices are **orthogonally** diagonalizable

Comment: @JohnHughes Indeed. I have edited my answer. Thank you.

Comment: Ah, I see. This makes a bit more explicit, of course, and is probably exactly what they were looking for.

Answer (score 2):

There is no connection with being symmetric, or real for that matter. For any square matrix $A$ over any field, $A−A^3$ is invertible if and only if none of $0$ and $\pm 1$ are eigenvalues of $A$.

Comment: Yeah, this is kind of what I figured, but I was feeling very unsure.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps it's just that you can say $A$ must be similar to a diagonal matrix $\pmatrix{a&& \\ & b & \\ & & c}$, $a, b, c \ne 0, \pm 1$.